# Stealth Paging in UI5

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to perform stealth paging on a `sap.ui.table.Table`? By stealth paging I mean, when scrolling (up or down) only a batch of records is retrieved. The current page is removed and replaced with the next batch of records. I don't want a technique that continuously appends to the data because I have a last button and it would take forever to load everything.

Would I use something like `getThreshold()` found [here](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/methods/getThreshold)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables in sapui5 already have this built in.

> a Table control can take care of only rendering the currently visible rows and use this ScrollBar control to make the user think he actually scrolls through a long list.

This can be found [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.ScrollBar.html).

SapUi5 is even cooler than I originally thought!